# TeamCity - find who triggered the first build in a build chain

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I have a build 'X', which is triggered by successful finished build 'Y', which is triggered manually by one of the developers.
I want to create a parameter in X with the name of the person who triggered Y.

Is it possible?
We're using teamcity-8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fully setup CI you can click "show changes from snapshot dependencies" in all the VCS locations, then you can see who made a change in source control.  Another way would be to setup the build chain, and then you can view the build chain to see what was the first component triggered then review the user who triggered the build.